# Dynamically update instance variable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, dynamic-variables

I would like to make an API call dynamically. API (Get) result must vary dynamically based on the query string passed.

I have hard coded the API URL without any query string, and supplied the API URL as an instance variable:

```
@apiRequest = HTTParty.get("http://localhost:1880/api/devices")
@parseApiRequest = JSON.parse(@apiRequest.body)
```

I want `@apiRequest` to change dynamically based on user input from a form (I had already developed a form that gets inputs from user's).

Is it possible to change the value of an instance variable dynamically? User's input value must be passed onto that controller as a query string.

Sample image that gets user input:
[Getting User Input](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qx1b4.png)

The instance variable must be updated dynamically as,

```
@apiRequest = HTTParty.get("http://localhost:1880/api/devices?device_id=123456")
```

Kindly suggest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply interpolate the dynamic data into the api request parameter string:

```
extraParamsOrPath = "assemble this from form inputs"
urlPrefix = "http://localhost:1880/"
@apiRequest = HTTParty.get("#{urlPrefix}/#{extraParamsOrPath}")
```

And make sure the user input is sanitized ;)

Comment: @FaizulHassan did it work for you, if so, please accept the answer ;)